# Error sending e-mail from Google VM

Tags: c#, email, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

I have a C# application that sends emails using the smtp of my customer and it is not working on **Google Cloud VM** (Windows), but it is working on Azure VM or any local machine.

The exception that is happening is:

> Failure sending mail.  Unable to
>   connect to the remote server  A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,  or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond [IP SMTP]

Is There some configuration on Google Cloud Console that I could try to solve it? Why I can't send emails from a Google VM?

Comment: did you consult with Google Clouds VM Ware Support perhaps you do not have the Relay Server setup correctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in Google Cloud docs that ports 587, 465 and 25 are blocked and there is no way to unblock it. The solution I found was ask to my customer to create a VPN connection on his SMTP server and I connected with it by another port.